# Time Calculator Incorrect Date Format

Tags: javascript, date, format

A kind soul gave me the following script a while back to calculate future dates while excluding weekends. It works like a charm, however on certain systems it displays the incorrect date format.

I'd like it to display the date in dd/mm/yyyy, however on some of my colleagues pc's its showing m/d/yyyy.

I've checked their Time and date settings and they're all correct.

It would really help if someone were able to help force this format by adding into the following script as I'm not Javascript coder by any means :(

```js
<script>
     var myDelayInDays=8, myDate=new Date();
     myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+myDelayInDays);
     if(myDate.getDay() == 0){//Sunday
       myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Tuesday
     }
     else if(myDate.getDay() == 6){//Saturday
       myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Monday
     }
     document.write('' + myDate.toLocaleDateString());
  </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toLocaleDateString will print the date in default format based on the user browser.
But you can specify the particular format by specifying the locale.

The en-GB locale will print the date in dd/mm/yyyy

```js
<script>
     var myDelayInDays=8, myDate=new Date();
     myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+myDelayInDays);
     if(myDate.getDay() == 0){//Sunday
       myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Tuesday
     }
     else if(myDate.getDay() == 6){//Saturday
       myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Monday
     }
     document.write('' + myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
  </script>
```

Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.write('' + myDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

use

```
var myDate=new Date(myDate);
var dateString=date.getDate()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(date.getFullYear());
document.write(dateString);
```

Since LocalDateString will differ for each machine

Comment: Why would it different for each machine if the users will all be in the same country?

Comment: Its depends on the time format that you set in ur machine. For example client time format and server time format need not to be same. Sending a toLocaleDateString to a server may cause bug.I expired real time.